# Detect and kill hung thread in C or C++ program

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I am writing a multi-threaded prgram in c++. I have created threads using pthread_create. I am also using pthread_join to wait for the threads to finish. When I create few threads less than 50 it works fine. But when I create more than 100 threads my program gets stuck at pthread_join. I want to detect and kill the hung threads so that program can continue.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to simply not hang threads in the first place? Killing threads, particularly in C++, has *substantial* doom-impending ramifications, including not firing cleanup code, destructors, etc. Patient: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." Doctor: "So, don't do that."

Comment: What is a "hung thread"? Would a thread doing `while (1);` be considered "hung"?

Comment: Killing threads is usually a very bad thing to do, as possible resources they have allocated will not be released. However, detecting a "hung" thread is simple: A so called *watchdog* variable. You have a boolean variable (preferably an a atomic) and the threads set it to a specific state (say `true`) in specific intervals. The main thread then check if the variable is e.g. `true` and then resets it to `false`. If the variable have not been set to `true` in some time, then the thread is probably "hung".

Comment: The best solution though, is to find out *why* the threads hang, and fix the root cause. Maybe it's a race-condition? Perhaps two or more threads attempt to lock a common lock in the wrong order and therefore gets "hung"?

Comment: Maybe the machine you're running isn't capable of handling this much of load, you need to show what those threads are doing.

Comment: Program works fine When I create few threads. There are no shared variables in the program. So, no chance of race conditions. Program get stuck sometimes when number of threads are more than 100. I am also not using dynamic memory inside threads. That is why I think it is safe to kill thread.

Comment: You might be thrashing with all the context switches between those threads.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: How about files? Sockets? Pipes? Anything that you "open" or "load" or "allocate" or "create" is a resource that needs to be released. And many such resource could be shared without you knowing it. Like for example files, are multiple threads reading from or writing to the same file? As you can see I'm only throwing up guesses here, because you have not provided us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend you take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "That is why I think it is safe to kill thread" you think wrong. Believe me it is much simpler to fix the root cause that to fight hidden problems.

Comment: Btw unless you have hundred cores on you box it is not good idea to create hundred threads.

Comment: @Slava well, the box I'm posting this on has four cores and 997 threads.  Firefox has 67 threads alone  It's no problem at all.  I agree that 997 running threads would be a big problem.

Comment: What @EugeneSh. says - are the 'hung' threads looping, (100% CPU), or blocked, (0% CPU)?  As others have commented, you need to find the root cause and fix it.

Comment: @MartinJames it is matter of problems, but if you have hundred of threads in an app that runs in 2 core machine - that app is poorly designed.

Comment: If threads are not using CPU too often then there is no link between number of threads and number of cores. @Martin James I know, I needs to find root cause but I am asking this question so that I can fix problem for short time until I found the root cause.